# Multiply conditions set in AssertJ assertions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

I'm trying to set multiply conditions on the assertJ and could not find in it examplesGit.

I currently write:

```
    assertThat(A.getPhone())
            .isEqualTo(B.getPhone());
    assertThat(A.getServiceBundle().getId())
            .isEqualTo(B.getServiceBundle().getId());
```

But want to have something like:

```
            assertThat(A.getPhone())
            .isEqualTo(B.getPhone())
            .And
            (A.getServiceBundle().getId())
            .isEqualTo(B.getServiceBundle().getId());
```

As if I use chaining this won't work because I need difference data (id and not phone). is there any possibility to mix it all to a one-assertJ command? It doesn't look like there could be any possibility for this (algorithm wise) but maybe some other idea to && on statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [soft assertions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/SoftAssertions.html) with AssertJ to combine multiple assertions and evaluate these in one go. Soft assertions allow to combine multiple assertions and then evaluate these in one single operation. It is a bit like a *transactional* assertion. You setup the assertion bundle and then commit it.

```
SoftAssertions phoneBundle = new SoftAssertions();
phoneBundle.assertThat("a").as("Phone 1").isEqualTo("a");
phoneBundle.assertThat("b").as("Service bundle").endsWith("c");
phoneBundle.assertAll();
```

It is a bit verbose, but it is an alternative to "&&"-ing your assertions. The error reporting is actually quite granular, so that it points to the partial assertions which fail. So the example above will print:

> ```
> org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertionError: 
> The following assertion failed:
> 1) [Service bundle] 
> Expecting:
>  <"b">
> to end with:
>  <"c">
> ```

Actually this is better than the "&&" option due to the detailed error messages.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to assertJ's `SoftAssertions` is JUnit's [`assertAll`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll(org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable...)):

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;

assertAll(
  () -> assertThat("a").as("Phone 1").isEqualTo("a"),
  () -> assertThat("b").as("Service bundle").endsWith("c")
);
```